# How do I make a webapp that doesn't have "global" pages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, web-applications

this might be a really simple question but I couldn't find an answer out there on the internet.

I'm not sure how exactly to word this question because I don't know the terminology, so I will give some examples to demonstrate what I am talking about.

I am trying to make a web app that involves two users, user 1 and user 2. User 1 will answer a certain number of questions and user 2 will do the same (possibly concurrently), then they will both be shown which questions they answered identically. My problem is: how do I show the users the questions locally in a manner that if user 2 goes to the webapp at the same time user 1 is using it, the server won't show them the same page/question?

I basically want the web app to be like a shopping web app (like the Walgreens one for example) in the way that each user using it sees something different and not the same HTML page that everyone else would (as would be the case with the Walgreens homepage). How would I go about accomplishing this?

I am sorry for how vague this question is, I just completed [this](https://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-mongodb/) tutorial and realized that I was quickly running into the problem detailed above and have never independently made a web app before. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I am looking for a more generalized/conceptual answer to how to solve this problem, I would never expect someone to actually code this out for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use socket information in node js side to construct the page based on the user that ask the resource. :)

Comment: I wouldn't use a socket on my cloud hosted Apache, costs would increase to clouds.